# Simple difficulty with HQL Query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I am having a trouble with executing an HQL query like this:

```
select new myPackage.view.CoverDocumentReportView(Re.code AS fulCd,
Re.creditPrice AS crtprc,
Re.debitPrice  AS dbtprc,
(Re.debitPrice - Re.debitPrice) AS redbtprc,
(Re.creditPrice- Re.creditPrice) AS recrtprc,
(Re.debitPrice-Re.creditPrice)   AS rem) 
from 
(select  fullCode as code, 
     sum(creditPrice) as creditPrice ,
     sum(debitPrice)  as debitPrice   
from    DocumentMaster DM,
     DocumentAccount   DA,
     Tree              T ,
     AccountTree       AT, 
     DocumentDetailed  DD 
where DM.id =  DA.documentMaster  and  
      DA.accountTree =  T.id      and   
      DA.accountTree =  AT.id     and   
      DD.documentAccount =  DA.id 
group by  DA.accountTree ) As Re
```

---

**1)**
If I execute this like:

```
SQLQuery crit = (SQLQuery) session
            .createSQLQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CoverDocumentReportView.class));
ArrayList<CoverDocumentReportView> li =  (ArrayList<CoverDocumentReportView>) crit.list();
```

> ERROR 2012-12-22 14:16:19,838 [http-8080-1] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.datx.web.accounting.view.CoverDocumentReportView(Re.code AS fulCd,
>     Re.creditP' at line 1

---

**2)**
If I execute it with this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CoverDocumentReportView.class));
ArrayList<CoverDocumentReportView> li =  (ArrayList<CoverDocumentReportView>)query.list();
```

The error will be:

> ERROR 2012-12-22 14:51:46,709 [http-8080-1] org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter : line 1:224: unexpected token: (
>   ERROR 2012-12-22 14:51:46,709 [http-8080-1] org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter : line 1:308: unexpected token: sum

What is the problem?

Comment: You might want to see here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: BTW, case sensitive was not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL and HQL are two different languages.

HQL doesn't support subqueries in from clauses, so this query can't be an HQL query.

And SQL doesn't know about Java objects, and doesn't have any `new()` function allowing to create them, so the query is not a valid SQL query either.

Make it a valid SQL query, execute it using `createSQLQuery()`, then iterate through the results and create instances of your objects from the returned rows. Or use a result transformer as you're doing, which will do that for you. the result transformer will use the aliases you assigned to the returned columns of the SQL query to create beans for you. You don't need any `new CoverDocumentReportView()` in the query to make that work. Read the javadoc for details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, changing it to SQL is not an option here. How can I make it work with HQL? It seems that HQL does support subqueries. I will do any necessary changes.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries : *Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.*

Comment: I see, but is there a way to have my desired SQL statement, safely transformed into HQL? A link or hint would suffice.

Comment: *Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.*. This means that you **can't** have a subquery in the `from` clause. So, no, this query can't be translated to HQL, because a `from` clause is not a `select` clause, and is not a `where` clause either. I don't see how it could be clearer.

Comment: Believe me: **I get it** :-) You don't need to repeat it every time. I think I'd better think of `how to write this sql without from clause to make it transformable to hql` myself.